# How to reuse complex component in Flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, code-reuse, flux

I have just started to use Flux in my project, but I find it difficult to reuse a component (or have multi instances in different places) when it's complex. By "complex" I mean a component includes some smaller components and may involves some interactions of changing some data. For example, a component containing a list, a adding new input and button.

I can come out with two ways of solving it:

1. Passing all functions that handling change events by props from
   parent, so the component will not know which action is really
   called. In this way, there will be a lot functions passing down for
   different levels' components.
2. Passing an 'identifier' object when calling
   action. In store it will access corresponding data located by the
   'identifier'. This way there is added logic and parameter
   "identifier".

I haven't found a best way of handling this, basicly because store and action in Flux are singleton. Is there any more elegant way to solve this? Thanks!